# Golang mongodb driver random errnotfound error for update query even document is present for the criteria

Tags: mongodb, go, mongoose

Golang mongodb driver random errnotfound error for update query even document is present for the criteria.

I am using golang with mongodb but facing some weird issue while updating document.For some random call it throws error "errNotFound" even document is present for given criteria.

it works well when query runs again.

Comment: We can't fix your code if you don't show us your code.  Also your first sentence doesn't make any sense. Is it meant to be an error message? Formatting would help.

Comment: its random error for sharded cluster

Comment: here is the issue https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/mongodb-user/FWpS1llOAnQ/gagNr5KtGAAJ

Comment: @Flimzy its a common problem of mongodb engine ...

Comment: @Flimzy see the discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/mongodb-user/FWpS1llOAnQ/gagNr5KtGAAJ